# How to improve speed using redis?

Tags: node.js, database, caching, redis, backend

I am a noobie in backend Development. I created a blog using express and MongoDB. I heard about redis which helps caching and reduce request serve time . So I decided to give it a try on my blog. I used a hashmap to store the title and content of the post and then render it using the ejs engine. I pretty much did everything right and the 'hmgetall' works but the problem is I dont see any improvement in speed .

Comment: have you tried logging / tracking your excecution time in regards to requests? And compared them to when using MongoDB?
Please post what you've tried to figure out if there were any improvement in speed. This way it is easier to get help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't optimize performance too early, because you don't know where the performance is now.

1. Use an apm product to monitor your services, such as newrelic.
2. Use apm to find the slowest interface in the service and optimize it with redis.

Cache is not a silver bullet, don't mess with it.

Comment: Actually I wanted use redis as a part of another project, so I was just testing it with a demo project before taking it to real project